# Nextjs environment variables seem to be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

After creating a new next.js project with npx create-next-app@latest and adding some environment variables on .env.local file I get this error when i run the server.

```
"Failed to load env from .env.local TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')"
```

I tried 3 times to create a nextjs project and it was always happening (OS Windows 11)

Comment: Can you share the contents/structure of your .env.local file?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu My .env.local file is on the root directory and the content is this:

`CRYPTO_SCRT='cryptosecret'
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://user:mongodb.net/dummy-data
JWT_SECRET='123jwtsecret'
JWT_EXPIRES_IN=30d`

I want to access these values only on sever, not client

Comment: Can you share how you are trying to access the values? Also, have you tried removing .local?

Comment: @PedroMendes I just added a getServerSideProps function in the index.js page and inside I console.log(process.env.CRYPTO_SCRT). Then I watch my IDE console and It logs "undefined" and then returns the error above. I tried without local also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the cause of the problem was that one of my .env variables included a '$' character, so the env file failed to load. Escaping the $ character with a \ solves the problem.